# Rendering object attributes in the view. - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

I have a view right now that displays a full object(I'll show code later). I want to display an attribute of each directly below the object. Here is some code.

### View

```
 <ul class="integration-list integration-list--compact">
  <%= render @integrations %>
 </ul>
```

An integration has a `filters attribute` I want to display the attribute for each integration directly below the object. Anyone know how I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
<%= render :partial => 'controller/partial', :collection => @objects %>
```

it will render the _integration partial for each integrations

```
<%= render :partial => 'integrations/integration', :collection => @integrations %>
```

Comment: Where do I put that line? Thanks for the help.

Comment: in view beetwen your `<ul>` tag